# .NET Compact COM interoperability

Tags: c#, .net, com, compact-framework

I have the following code in a full .NET framework solution:

```
public delegate int CreateObjectDelegate(
            [In] ref Guid classID,
            [In] ref Guid interfaceID,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] out object outObject);

...

var createObject = (NativeMethods.CreateObjectDelegate)
    Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(
        NativeMethods.GetProcAddress(_modulePtr, "CreateObject"),
            typeof (NativeMethods.CreateObjectDelegate));
object result;
Guid interfaceId = _guid;
Guid classID = _classId;
createObject(ref classID, ref interfaceId, out result);
```

The purpose is to create the needed COM object at runtime. Is it possible with any .NET compact framework?

Note that it doesn't have Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer.

Comment: Why don't you just P/Invoke CoCreateInstance() directly?  Or use a type library and TlbImp.exe?

Comment: I want to dynamically load different in general but having much in common COM libraries. I gave up and used P/Invoke CreateObject, so I am always bound to the library I p/invoke this function from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whatever (absolutely stupid) reason, the CF doesn't include Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer.  I've been asking the team for it for years.  There's simply no way to take a function pointer and call it in the CF.